# background_image support multiple image size?

Tags: theme-development, multisite, custom-background

Does background_image support showing multiple image sizes like feature image? I can see multiple files were created when I uploaded a file. How do I use those images or does background_image not allow that to happen?

Something like `get_background_image('large')` [doesn't work] or something where I can insert the dimensions after the file name like the-url-to-the-image-1024x768.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using `str_replace`.

First the location of the background image is stored in a string:

```
<?php $backimg = get_background_image(); ?>
```

Then perform a string and replace where the `.jpg` is removed at the end of the `$backimg` and is stored as `$bgraw`

```
<?php $bgraw = str_replace('.jpg','',$backimg);?>
```

It output as:

```
http://locationurl.com/path-to-upload-folder/background-file
```

The .jpg is removed; from there you insert the file you want to use. For example, I have a custom image where the dimensions are 1280px wide by 450px height. The image is created as fileimage.jpg-1280x450.jpg.

To use that image, take the stored value of `$bgraw` and add `-1280x450.jpg` or whatever file you want to use instead.

```
<?php echo $bgraw . '-1280x450.jpg' ;?>
```

That outputs as:

```
http://locationurl.com/path-to-upload-folder/background-file-1280x450.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use those images having different sizes.

When you upload an image, by default wordpress creates four images with different sizes like **50 X 50**, **150  X 150**, **300 X 225** and **500 X 500** and original size of image.So you can use any of them by following code :

```
    the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> Thumbnail

    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
    the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
    the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
    the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified)

    the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions(this will be cropped as per size given by you)
```

You can use that images in your background but you need to add custom CSS to make it happen as per your desired result.

**NOTE**: You can always change size of image by going to admin dashboard and then `Setting > Media`.

Comment: This isn't for feature image, this is for Custom Background on a theme.

Comment: Are you using default theme or some free wordpress theme ?If free theme, then can you please provide link of that ?

Comment: It's an internal site and I'm designing my own theme.

Comment: You can use `$media_dir = wp_upload_dir('2014/11');<style type="text/css" media="all">
body { background-image: url("<?php echo $media_dir['url']; ?>/images/background.jpg");
background-repeat: repeat-x; }
</style>`
So it will add the background image.
You can find more about [wp_upload_dir](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir).
Define above code in your `header.php`